# Wagtail: Nested Inline Panels

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I would like to place an Inline panel into an Inline panel, and place that Inline panel into a Snippet. According to these links, Wagtail has not supported nesting Inline panels in the past:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wagtail/3i-THVOV7AI/zCo58xfu1IEJ
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail/sJbFVc5gvmw

Since these are a few years old, does anyone know if Wagtail can handle nested Inline panels now? If not, is there a newer workaround for implementing a nested Inline panel into a Snippet?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, Wagtail still does not provide any solution for nested inlines.

Comment: @help-info.de no, this is an answer.

Comment: @Zoe - thanks for hint - I was guided by the limitation "According to my knowledge.". I deleted review comment and will watch for cleaning.